# Adapt existing repository to subversion trunk/branch structure

Tags: svn

I have started working on an already-existing project that uses Subversion for version control. I've only used Git before, so I've been going through various svn tutorials. Nearly all of them use a trunk/branch/tag file structure for the project. I would like to do the same, since I will both be editing the project (results pushed to master) as well as doing custom things on my own (results kept local). However, the project doesn't have this format; its `.svn` just lies in its root folder.

How do I create branches for a project organized this way? I've tried creating my own repository (`svnadmin create`) with the trunk/branch/tag structure and then checking out the project into the trunk, but I can't figure out how to make *my* root project directory a working copy. (`svn relocate` requires that where I try to relocate to is itself a working copy.) Even using `svnadmin` at all seems wrong, since that would create a repository whose member is also a repository, and doing that didn't add a `.svn` to that root folder.

Let me know if what I want to do is unclear, or of any useful details I should include about the filestructure, checkout process, etc. I'm really struggling with describing exactly what I did and what I've considered trying.

Edit: I found [Subversion branching without having canonical directory structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6728155/subversion-branching-without-having-canonical-directory-structure). This has some of the same elements. However, since I'm not the administrator or project lead, I want to be able to pull remote updates to the `trunk`. Moving around its `.svn` folder doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.... I had written something that was a response for a *different* question altogether, sorry for that.... so let me try gain:

Just like on my previous response, the root problem remains the same: you want to tackle svn with git's mindset... and it's not possible. So....

How can you create branches and stuff that will remain local: **you can't** .... with svn. Unlike git, on svn there's a single repo where *everything* is held (except for the different developer's working copy). All branches, tags, revisions, etc, they are there, in a single spot... not much is kept on the working copies.... and no branches outside of the central repo.

But then... the trick is that I said *with svn*. If you use git, you can take advantage of a git plugin that can be used to crossover between git and svn. It will allow you to be synchronized with an svn repo *just as if it were a git remote* and you can take advantage of git's goodies like local branches.

I'm not saying that it's trivial to deal with it, but with a little practice it will allow you to work with a lot more flexibility that working with plain svn. Hope this is enough for you to be able to achieve your goals.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn

Comment: I did eventually come to the conclusion that I just needed to tackle this with git, for a number of reasons. Thanks for pointing me towards this plugin, it might make it much easier to blend the two.